# Find a the minimum number $t$

Tags: calculus

Find the number $t$ such that area below $y=\frac{e^x}{x}$ for $x>0$ and above $[t,t+1]$ is a minimum.

I looked at it as an optimization problem, and did the following

$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{e^x}{x}=\frac{e^x(x-1)}{x^2}=0$ => x=1

therefore for t=1 the area is minimum. Is that the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not the right approach.

For any $t$, the area below the curve is
$$A(t) = \int_t^{t+1} \frac{e^x}{x} dx.$$
Do you see why?

Now you want to minimize this area, which means taking the derivative of $A$ with respect to $t$, and setting it equal to zero.

$$0 = \frac{d}{dt} A(t) = \frac{d}{dt} \int_t^{t+1} \frac{e^x}{x}\,dx = \ldots?$$
can you take it from here?